# Publishing in parallel for different WP versions vs publishing for different android versions

Tags: android, compatibility, windows-phone-7

Prompted by some rant regarding Microsofts mobile update policy, I started to wonder: Is the situation for windows phone devices stuck with WP 7.x actually worse or better than for Android devies, that have outdated versions (e.g. 2.3)?

E.g. how difficult is it to develop Apps to be compatible with different windows phone versions compared to different Android versions? When publishing Apps, does the interface encourage you to publish for older WP versions (e.g. by selecting "publish for windows 7.x *and* 8.x" by default) more or less than the interface for publishing on Google Play?

What about practical App availability? Are WP8 apps as likely to be available for 7.x as well as Android apps are likely to be available for 2.3 (or older)?

Similiarily, do WP security updates have to pass the often uninterested manufacturers (as with Android) or are they delivered directly to end users?

Comment: Software development questions are better asked on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Phone and Android market do share some similarities when it comes to development and devices. As there are Android devices (either old or low end) that only run 2.2 or 2.3 and will never see 4.x and above, Windows Phone has many millions of devices that run WP7.5/7.8 that will never run 8.x.

Making a decision as to which version of WP to support (or both) comes down to many factors, here are just a few...

- Does your target market still contain a large % of WP7 devices
- Does WP7 have all the features your app needs or do you need the newer APIs provided by WP8 (nearly all WP7 apps run on WP8)?
- Do you have the time/resources to make a WP7 and WP8 app (you can share resource between the two, so you’re not making two separate apps)

**Publishing**

When publishing apps, the Dev Center doesn’t push you either way but the documentation, especially the newer APIs do favor WP8. The Windows Phone Developer Blog has a [great post on how publishing both a WP7 and WP8 app works](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/01/15/app-submission-tips-for-windows-phone-7-and-windows-phone-8.aspx).

As for which version of WP is more poplar, that varies from country to country. An article on [All About Windows Phone shows recent data from AdDuplex](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/17265_AdDuplex_April_reports_shows_r.php) - this should give you a good idea of how things are. Regardless, it’s always recommended to have [some form of analytics in your app](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_add_Flurry_Analytics_to_your_Windows_Phone_app) so you can monitor what OS version and devices are being used over time.

**Platform updates**

OS updates have to approved by the manufactures (Nokia, Samsung, HTC, etc) and operators. So far, manufactures pass on the updates almost straight away as they don’t customise the platform like Android OEMs do, but some operators do delay a month or two due to ‘testing’ - but the situation is nowhere near as bad as it is with Android where [some updates can take 6+ months to appear](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/02/two-year-old-phone-receives-15-month-old-software-update/), if at all.